# Distributing 6 distinct balls among 10 distinct boxes such that at least one box has more than one ball.

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

I want to distribute $ 6 $ distinct balls in $ 10 $ distinct boxes such that at least one box contains more than $ 1 $ ball. Did I calculate correct?

There are $ \binom{10}1 = 10 $ ways to choose a box.

We will choose $ 2 $ balls and put them in the box we have chosen - $ \binom{6}2 = 15 $

We will now distribute the rest of the balls - $ 10^4 $.

Therefore, by the rule of product, the answer is $ 10\cdot15\cdot10^4 $.

Comment: This is not correct, as you are overcounting arrangements in which more than one box has more than one ball (as well as arrangements in which a box contains more than $2$ balls).  I suggest: work off the complement.  Count the arrangements in which no box contains more than $1$ ball.

Comment: It is far too high, as there are $10^6$  ways of putting the $6$ balls into the $10$  boxes so your result should be less than this rather than $1.5 \times 10^6$

Comment: It is probably simpler to count how many ways you can put 6 balls in 10 boxes without any box having 2 or more balls, then subtract from the number of ways to put 6 balls in 10 boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Lets solve the question using complement rule as @lulu mentioned such that all possible distributions without restriction - the number of distributions where no box contain more than one balls.

- All possible distributions without restriction = $10^6$
- the number of distributions where no box contain more than one balls: Select $6$ boxes among $10$ boxes to put the balls , and distribute these $6$ distinct balls into $6$ distinct boxes by $6!$ . Hence , $$\binom{10}{6}6!$$

So , $$10^6 -\binom{10}{6}6!=848,800$$